# Constructing an unrestricted grammar for XWX, where W is the reverse of X

Tags: formal-grammars

I'm trying to construct an unrestricted grammar for strings of the form XWX, where W is the reverse of X, over the alphabet {a, b}.

I think I can apply similar logic to the a^nb^nc^n solution (below), but am running into issues.

```
S -> 
S -> aSBC
CB -> BC
aB -> ab
bB -> bb
bC -> bc
cC -> cc
```

I've thought about it a lot, and have tried starting off with the following, but cannot make the needed reordering steps work:

```
S -> 
S -> aSXA
S -> bSYB
```

A shove in the right direction would be helpful!

Comment: If you add one rule $\#\to\epsilon$ to the grammar [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/150093/91753), will it work?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of that solution is to generate $a^nY$, where $Y$ is a bunch of nonterminals, such that $Y$ can only generate $b^nc^n$.

To apply the same idea here, you'd want to generate $xY$ such that $x \in X$, $Y$ is a bunch of nonterminals, and $Y$ can only generate $x^{-1}x$.

So what I'd start with is

```
S -> 
S -> aSA
S -> bSB
S -> cSC
S -> dSD
```

(and so on for each character in the alphabet).

Now comes the tricky part: how to expand those nonterminals into $x^{-1}x$? E.g., CBA needs to generate cbaabc.

Just like in the example you're following, work from left to right. Only when C has a terminal to its left, replace it with cC'. Send C' to the right and expand it there only when it has arrived.

Tricks: you can change S into T and keep T around as a marker. You can mark the end of the word with a nonterminal and remove that mark when you're done. It's much like programming Turing machines.

Good luck.